# How to make a postback when the user clicks the back button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, webforms, page-refresh, dopostback

I have a webforms web app, and all I need to do is, when a user clicks on the browser back button, I want to make a post-back or reload my page so it makes the post-back itself so new data is loaded. 
I am using a library called [jQuery-backDetect](http://www.vvaves.net/jquery-backDetect/)
which allows me to detect browser's back button click and I try to do is to make a post-back using **__doPostback('arg1', 'arg2')**. But it won't work at all. 
And the strangest thing here is that, if I have the browser's debugger (in developer tools) open, or I pause the code execution using a breakpoint, it works perfectly. Here is a simple code I have written:

```
$(window).load(function(){
$('body').backDetect(function(){
// Callback function
  debugger;
  __doPostback('arg1', 'arg2');
});
```

});

I have tried to go through all the question here but they didn't help.

As strange as the question sounds, I really hope someone can help me. Thanks

Comment: Disable browser back button and make your own back navigation

Comment: I'll definitely try it

Answer (score 0):

You might consider wrapping the page content in an UpdatePanel, that might help create the behavior you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I will try it.